# Disabling the left window corner's menu in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, context-menu

When I pin my tabs, I always have a problem while selecting the first tab.

The problem is that the left window's menu appear (which is obvious if I can't reach with accuracy the first tab).

The question is : is there a method to disable that contextuel menu to appear in Chrome ?

Regards.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all items. See link: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html

**removeAll**
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function callback)

Removes all context menu items added by this extension.

**Parameters**

callback

( optional function )
    Called when removal is complete.

**Callback function**

If you specify the callback parameter, it should specify a function that looks like this:

function() {...};

Comment: but this is for inner pages conntextual menus. My question is about the Window ... you know, when you click in Windows on the left window's icon (upper left), there is a menu that appears. I'm afraid that this kind of functionalities are dealt from Windows more than the application. But, I'm sure there a solution.